# Compare data from edit text with data from if statement

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm making a quiz app. User has to finish the phrase shown on display and write the name of the car in the edittext, after pushing on button, if the answer right, edittext become green, if doesn't, become red. If all answers right (green), intent move on next activity.

I have some difficulties with if statement edit text become red even the answer was right. Also how to make INTENT to move on next activity if all right, if not it doesn't move?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et_one_one, et_one_two, et_one_three;
Button buttonCheck;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et_one_one = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_one_one);
    et_one_two = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_one_two);
    et_one_three = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_one_three);

    final String t1 = et_one_one.getText().toString();
    final String t2 = et_one_two.getText().toString();
    final String t3 =  et_one_three.getText().toString();

    buttonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheck);

    buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               if (t1.equals("maserati")){
                et_one_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else {
                et_one_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if (t2.equals("mercedes")){
                et_one_two.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else{
                et_one_two.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
            if (t3.equals("bmw")){
                et_one_three.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            }
            else{
                et_one_three.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're changing the color of just the `et_one_one` each time in your if else statements. Shouldn't it be for different edittexts?

```
buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean allAnswersCorrect = true;
        String t1 = et_one_one.getText().toString();
        String t2 = et_one_two.getText().toString();
        String t3 =  et_one_three.getText().toString();
        if (t1.equals("maserati")){
            et_one_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else {
            allAnswersCorrect = false;
            et_one_one.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        if (t2.equals("mercedes")){
            et_one_two.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else{
            allAnswersCorrect = false;
            et_one_two.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        if (t3.equals("bmw")){
            et_one_three.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
        else{
            allAnswersCorrect = false;
            et_one_three.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
        if(allAnswersCorrect){
            Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, YourSecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
});
```

Maintain a `allAnswersCorrect` boolean to check whether your answers are correct or not. If all are correct the move to your next activity.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't notice, but it doesn't change color on green

Comment: Another problem is, that you set the values to the strings in the `onClick` method. Check my updated answer.

Comment: THANK YOU it helped! But how to make INTENT to move on next activity if all right, if not it doesn't move?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `t2.equals("maserati")`, and it will be ok.

Comment: Than you need to reconsider the logic in you event listener. What are the values of t1,t2 and t3 in the moment when you press the button?

Comment: You are changing the et_one_one color in the all 3 cases, maybe you want to change et_one_two in the second case and et_one_three in the third

Comment: Thanks I fixed it, but color doesn't change on green even if the answer is right